# How do I measure information loss when converting categorical data to numerical?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, information-theory, data-preprocessing

Assume that a dataset has a mix of categorical and numerical attributes. The dataset has to undergo numeric processing which necessitates the conversion of the categorical attributes to numeric/quantified form.

But if we do this - irrespective of the strategy we employ [like dummy variables/probability weights etc.] - do we always stand to lose information? How does one measure this information loss?

Any references or resource links would be most helpful!

Thanks in advance

Comment: good question, i would think to use entropy or some related metric, but never seen how this been done.

Comment: If you use dummy variables, you won't lose information, since you can reconstruct the categorical variable - without error - from the dummies.